# How to add <div> in <form> using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can add `<div>` element to form.

Tx

Comment: Guys Make sure you add comment for down voting this question :)

Comment: Didn't downvoted you but you should be more specific and give more details about your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
//find form
var form=document.getElementById("MyFormID");

//find div
var div=document.createElement('div');

//add text to div
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("My New Div"));

//append div to form
form.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, though you're not giving much to go on, it'd look something like this:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Hi!, I'm div content";
form.appendChild(div);
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rHm4w/).

Comment: @BreakHead - When are you running it?  If you're running it in the `<head>` before the `<form>` is present in the page for example, it won't find the `<form>` to add it to, make sure you're running it after it's in the DOM, e.g. placing your script at the end of the `<body>` or running it `onload`.